# KDE Dolphin: How to change the current directory by code in the folder pane?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, dolphin

I'd like to have a dolphin (KDE 4.13.3) service menu with that I can change the current opened folder/directory to another one.

To be more precisely, I want to go directly to the real path/target of a link folder.

The code itself is quite simple:

```
cd "$(realpath %f)"
```

Well, it changes the current directory but it does not open it in the folder pane.

How can I manage that? Is there a way anyway?

Comment: Typing `f="tmp"; cd $(realpath $f)` in to the terminal pane of a dolphin window causes the folder pane to change to the specified folder for me. Is that what you're trying to do? [Dolphin 17.04.3, KDE Framework 5.44]

Comment: No, sorry, but thanks anyway.
"$f" is used as a placeholder for the currently (single) selected file/folder that is handed over to the service menu. So it is already set. 
The command works though in the terminal pane, but somehow it has no effect on the folder pane.

Comment: Sorry, correction:

The command works though from the terminal pane, but somehow it has no effect from within the folder pane when I call it through the service menu. 
The service menu itself is correct and well formatted as it should be.

Comment: I presume the trouble is that the command is executed in a new sub-shell/tty which has no effect on the calling process.

Comment: Ah, you're running that code from a script? If so then yes, cd operates on a subshell which is closed when the script exits. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27139/script-to-change-current-directory-cd-pwd

Comment: Thanks again, but this also dosen't solve my problem. BTW: I made a mistake. It should be "%f" instead of "$f".

Anyhow, he point is that the .desktop file for KDE's service menu seems to run completely different. It is not a separate sub-shell that is run. If I let this command run from a script I need to use the source command to have effect on the terminal, but it still doesn't work from die service menu in the folder pane.

Comment: _Correction:_ […] but it still doesn’t work from within the service menu inside the folder pane.
_(sorry, my fingers deny to obey )_

Comment: Don't know earlier versions , I'm using Plasma 5.19.5, Dolphin 20.08.2 in Ubuntu 20.10, there is the option `Show Target` in the right-click menu, it will open the real path in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this question – in the meantime I found a *quite dirty* workaround:

First of all you need a script (e.g. `cd-dolphin`) to proceed some `cd` commands in the Konsole pane by using `qdbus` with the Dolphin API.

`qdbus` is almost self explaning with its help option (*e.g. `qdbus *dolphin*` gives the list of the servicename for all running dolphin instances*).

Now following `qdbus` actions must be taken:

1. open the terminal/Konsole pane

*Caution: You need to give it a little time to react! If you throw the following commands directly afterwards they won't be executed! Trick is to just send some text to display like "Please wait…".*

2. run the intended `cd` command (*e.g. `cd /path/to/folder`*)

*Remark: This still does **not** open the desired folder in the folder pane **if** this folder is on another partition/file system! Hence here's my dirty workaround as this command (normally) does **not** change to another fs:*

3. change to parent: `cd ..`

***Now** the folder change is also executed in the folder pane. To finally come to your destined folder:*

4. go back: `cd -`
5. (optional) close the Konsole pane

Finally you can add a servicemenu to execute this script on your desired link folder in the folder pane (*e.g.: `Exec=cd-dolphin "$(realpath %f)"`*).

Et voìla, that's it.

Hope it's useful for someone …